# How can I use sed to replace an entire line even if it only has one phrase to replace?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to make a bash script that goes into the /etc/login.defs file and changes password requirements for a cybersecurity competition. I am rather new to bash and the sed command. I would like to know how I can replace an entire line of text even if only part of the line is what I search for. For example if I want to change the maximum days you can keep a password to 7 the default looks like this:

`PASS_MAX_DAYS    99999`

It works for me to just run this command in the script:

`sed -i 's/PASS_MAX_DAYS    99999/PASS_MAX_DAYS    7/' /etc/login.defs`

But if I run this and the login.defs file isn't at the default settings it won't work. Is there a way for me to just search for `PASS_MAX_DAYS` and have it replace the entire line with `PASS_MAX_DAYS    7`?

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I haven't been able to find anything that answers my question.

Comment: Please try `sed -i 's/PASS_MAX_DAYS.*/PASS_MAX_DAYS    7/' /etc/login.defs`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can extend the pattern to include the whole text

```
sed -i 's/PASS_MAX_DAYS .*/PASS_MAX_DAYS    7/' /etc/login.defs
```

The `.*` in the pattern will include anything after the 'PASS_MAX_DAYS ' in the replaced text

Comment: this is IMO easier to crasp than the next one, just that [[:space:]] (like written below) is more robust, e.g. TAB could be used as separator.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "address" in sed (see manual for details):

```
sed -i -e "/^PASS_MAX_DAYS[[:space:]]/c \PASS_MAX_DAYS    7/" /etc/login.defs
```